# flask: error_handler for blueprints

Tags: http-status-code-404, blueprint, flask

Can error_handler be set for a blueprint?

```
@blueprint.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'This page does not exist', 404
```

edit:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/18413ed1bf08261acf6d40f8ba65a98ae586bb29/flask/blueprints.py

you can specify an app wide and a blueprint local error_handler

Comment: The errorhandler() on a blueprint doesn't work reliably. Sometimes it doesn't get used. Makes implementing SPA with client side routing rather annoying.

Answer (score 48):

You can use `Blueprint.app_errorhandler` method like this:

```
bp = Blueprint('errors', __name__)

@bp.app_errorhandler(404)
def handle_404(err):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@bp.app_errorhandler(500)
def handle_500(err):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

Comment: Even with this in place, `abort(404)` in the blueprint's views would be handled by app's error handler and not this. See [Flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) for it for more info.

Comment: Can someone edit/comment on how you would call this app_errorhandler from another blueprint?  Is there a flask.redirect() that I need to use? I get this `Could not build url for endpoint 'BaseBP.ErrorHandler'`

Answer (score 23):

`errorhandler` is a method inherited from Flask, not Blueprint.
If you are using Blueprint, the equivalent is `app_errorhandler`.

The documentation suggests the following approach:

```
def app_errorhandler(self, code):
        """Like :meth:`Flask.errorhandler` but for a blueprint.  This
        handler is used for all requests, even if outside of the blueprint.
        """
```

Therefore, this should work:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

USER = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@USER.app_errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """ Return error 404 """
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

On the other hand, while the approach below did not raise any error for me, it didn't work:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

USER = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@USER.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """ Return error 404 """
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The documentation says we must use errorhandler and not app_errorhandler. Did you notice that ?

Answer (score 3):

add error handling at  application level using the request proxy object:

```
from flask import request,jsonify

@app.errorhandler(404)
@app.errorhandler(405)
def _handle_api_error(ex):
if request.path.startswith('/api/'):
    return jsonify(ex)
else:
    return ex
```

[flask Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#error-handlers)

Answer (score 2):

I too couldn't get the top rated answer to work, but here's a workaround.

You can use a catch-all at the **end** of your Blueprint, not sure how robust/recommended it is, but it does work. You could also add different error messages for different methods too.

```
@blueprint.route('/<path:path>')
def page_not_found(path):
    return "Custom failure message"
```

Answer (score 2):

I combined previous [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951085/1037567) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58053040/1037567) with the official docs from Flask, section '[Returning API Errors as JSON](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/#returning-api-errors-as-json)', in order to provide a more general approach.

Here is a working PoC that you can copy and paste on your registered blueprint API route handler (e.g. `app/api/routes.py`):

```
    from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

    @blueprint.app_errorhandler(HTTPException)
    def handle_exception(e):
        """Return JSON instead of HTML for HTTP errors."""
        # start with the correct headers and status code from the error
        response = e.get_response()
        # replace the body with JSON
        response.data = json.dumps({
            "code": e.code,
            "name": e.name,
            "description": e.description,
        })
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprised others didn't mention miguelgrinberg's excellent tutorial.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling

I found the sentry framework for error handling (links below). Seems overly complex. not sure of the threshold where it becomes useful.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/flask/

Answer (score -10):

Flask [doesnt support blueprint level error handlers for 404 and 500 errors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler). A BluePrint is a leaky abstraction. Its better to use a new WSGI App for this, if you need separate error handlers, this makes more sense.

Also i would recommend not to use flask, it uses globals all over the places, which makes your code difficult to manage if it grows bigger.

Comment: downvoted, because flask recommendation is highly subjective and has nothing to do with the question asked