# How to register blueprint level error handler in Flask 1.0.2?

Tags: python, flask

[This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler) article for flask 1.0.x mentions we must use app_errorhandler (example:@bp.app_errorhandler)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951085/1779091) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58053040/1779091) SO answers also mention that we must use app_errorhandler (example:@bp.app_errorhandler)

[This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/blueprints/#error-handlers) article for flask 1.0.x mentions we must use errorhandler (example: @bp.errorhandler)

Why does documentation for 1.0.x mention 2 different things and which is the correct approach to register blueprint level error handler in Flask 1.0.2?

Answer (score -1):

There are no correct or incorrect approach for this kind of situation,

I definitely recommend you to use the Blueprint level error handler `@bp.errorhandler`, but for specific errors that are directly related to **Models/Helpers/Services/...etc** inside of your Blueprint execution.

However, I recommend you to handle errors that are common on all blueprints and their responses are pretty much the same on each blueprint, with your Flask app error handler `@app.errorhandler`.

This way you will remove any duplicate logic for error handling.

Comment: What situation do you refer to? The documentation for 1.0.x shows both approaches - but using the app_errorhandler doesn't work for me - does it work for you?

Comment: if `app_errorhandler` doesn't do it for you, then use `bp_errorhandler`,
What worked for me, is putting all common error handlers on `app_errorhandler`, and blueprint specific error handlers on the blueprint